# Expected number of rounds of flipping n fair coins?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Given $n$ fair coins, we define round $i$ as flipping all of them and obtain one observation $\vec{o_i}$.

We know the domain $O$ has $2^n$ variations.

If the game is designed as terminate as whenever all $2^n$ variations have being observed. What's the expected number of rounds $I$ for the game to terminate?

Even though all the coins are fair, but not necessarily independent. Assume we design the procedure of producing $\vec{o}$ and we know the correlation $\Sigma^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the coupon collector's problem?  You expect about $2^n \log(2^n)$ tries if everything is nominal-probability of heads is $\frac 12$ and coins are independent.  You allude to other conditions but I don't think in a way that one can make use of.

Comment: In the independent case it is a rephrasing of the coupon collector's problem: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem. According to the article the expected number of rounds scales like $2^n \log(2^n)$.

Comment: thanks for replying, yeah I'm aware of coupon collector's problem. the difficulty here is dependencies. wondering if there is any general solution for correlated observations

Comment: I assume you mean that _observations_ (e.g. vectors $o_1$ and $o_2$) are still independent, and it's just the coins within an observation (i.e. _entries_ in the vector) that are dependent.  If my assumption is correct, then you simply have vectors which are not equi-probable.  This is akin to coupon collector problem where the coupons are not equi-probable, which is mentioned in the 4th bullet of [this wikiepedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations).

Comment: yes, your assumption does hold, thanks for the insight! Do you mind elaborate more and maybe make an answer?

Comment: I think i find some clue from [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p33), they provided a bound on the expected number which is related to the rarest observation/ commonest observation   * n*log(n). And in my case n is actually 2^n, given the covariance does not degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of rounds corresponds to a coupon collector's problem. 
But as the question's requirement that coins are not necessarily independent from each other. So it's not going to be a standard coupon collector's problem but a non-uniform coupon collector's problem.

The expected number of rounds is going to depend on the probability of rarest observation $P(\vec{o_r})$ and the most common observation $P(\vec{o_c})$.

Based on this [paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p33).

The expected number is going to be bounded between $O(\frac{P(\vec{o_c})}{P(\vec{o_r})} * 2^n * log(2^n))$ and $O(\frac{P(\vec{o_r})}{P(\vec{o_c})} * 2^n * log(2^n))$

Comment: It’s a pity that I can’t find any resources from $\Sigma$ to $ P(\vec{o_c}) $ or $P(\vec{o_r})$